# Check if a DriverKit driver has been enabled in the iOS settings

Tags: ios, ipad, settings, driverkit

I have an app that contains a DriverKit dext bundled in. I'm trying to check if the user has enabled the driver through the Settings in the app-specific settings page (under the DRIVERS subheading) or in Privacy & Security > Drivers.

Unfortunately since this toggle field is automatically created by the iPad OS, it's not in my Settings.bundle that I create for my app. So I can't load it into the NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults, and it doesn't appear to be in the standardUserDefaults on its own like some of the other settings. Is there somewhere I can get this value?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a direct method, but you can indirectly deduce that your dext isn't being loaded by registering for IOKit match notfications in your app for the device your driver is supposed to be matching too. If your app detects the device, but no driver instance turns up for it, you can direct users to enable the driver.